# combobox not getting displayed

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ms-access

So, my requirement was to Display Records From Database Using JTable in Java. I referred the [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fd0172/display-records-from-database-using-jtable-in-java/).
But the error is that when I run it in Eclipse, I can't see the combobox as it should ideally appear. How to fix it ?

```
 import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

    public class DisplayEmpData extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        JFrame frame1;
        JLabel l0, l1, l2;
        JComboBox c1;
        JButton b1;
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs, rs1;
        Statement st, st1;
        PreparedStatement pst;
        String ids;
        static JTable table;
        String[] columnNames = {"User name", "Email", "Password", "Country"};
        String from;

        DisplayEmpData() {

            l0 = new JLabel("Fatching Employee Information");
            l0.setForeground(Color.red);
            l0.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            l1 = new JLabel("Select name");
            b1 = new JButton("submit");

            l0.setBounds(100, 50, 350, 40);
            l1.setBounds(75, 110, 75, 20);
            b1.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 20);
            b1.addActionListener(this);

            setTitle("Fetching Student Info From DataBase");
            setLayout(null);
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(500, 500);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            add(l0);
            add(l1);;
            add(b1);
            try {

                String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\users\\ppreeti\\emp_details.accdb";
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
                /*con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcndesktop07:1521:xe", "sandeep", "welcome");*/
                st = con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("select uname from emp");
                Vector v = new Vector();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    ids = rs.getString(1);
                    v.add(ids);
                }
                c1 = new JComboBox(v);
                c1.setBounds(150, 110, 150, 20);

                add(c1);
                st.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
                showTableData();
            }

        }

        public void showTableData() {

            frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //TableModel tm = new TableModel();
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    //DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(tm.getData1(), tm.getColumnNames());
    //table = new JTable(model);
            table = new JTable();
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            from = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();
    //String textvalue = textbox.getText();
            String uname = "";
            String email = "";
            String pass = "";
            String cou = "";

            try {
                pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from emp where UNAME='" + from + "'");
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                int i = 0;
                if (rs.next()) {
                    uname = rs.getString("uname");
                    email = rs.getString("umail");
                    pass = rs.getString("upass");
                    cou = rs.getString("ucountry");
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{uname, email, pass, cou});
                    i++;
                }
                if (i < 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            frame1.add(scroll);
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            frame1.setSize(400, 300);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new DisplayEmpData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). Factor out the DB by hard-coding some data.

Comment: BTW - a simpler approach is to add the combo. at start-up, give it some data to suggest a size, then disable it until needed.  On need, populate it with meaningful data and set it enabled.

Comment: So how should I make the combobox appear through my code ? I don't have any connectivity isues as such..just want to make the combobox appear

Comment: crossposted: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/88015-combobox-not-getting-displayed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is you adding combobox after setting frame's visibily=true. Please add all the components before setting frame's visibilty. I changed your constructor. Please note that using a null layout is not a good habbit (I think so) use any of [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

```
DisplayEmpData() {

        l0 = new JLabel("Fatching Employee Information");
        l0.setForeground(Color.red);
        l0.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        l1 = new JLabel("Select name");
        b1 = new JButton("submit");

        l0.setBounds(100, 50, 350, 40);
        l1.setBounds(75, 110, 75, 20);
        b1.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 20);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("Fetching Student Info From DataBase");
        setLayout(null);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(l0);
        add(l1);;
        add(b1);
        try {

            Vector v = new Vector();

            String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\users\\ppreeti\\emp_details.accdb";
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
            /*con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcndesktop07:1521:xe", "sandeep", "welcome");*/
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select uname from emp");

            while (rs.next()) {
                ids = rs.getString(1);
                v.add(ids);
            }
            c1 = new JComboBox(v);
            c1.setBounds(150, 110, 150, 20);

            add(c1);
            st.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, my advice is to use more meaningful names for methods and fields in your code: it may look crisp clear to you now, but for both an external reader and yourself in a couple of month what the code does won't be apparent at all.

That said, you are probably better off using a `LayoutManager`, that ensures correct `Component` placement and visibility along platforms (as @Andrew Thompson pointed out already).

Basically speaking, first step is to create a JPanel and add it to your JFrame:

```
JPanel framePanel;
framePanel = new JPanel();
this.add(framePanel);
```

When no arguments are specified in the `JPanel()` constructor, the layout is automatically set as a `BorderLayout`. This layout has 5 areas you can place a component in: North, South, West, East, Center.

You can now add other `JPanels` to your `framePanel` like so:

```
JPanel northPanel;
JPanel southPanel;
JPanel westPanel;
JPanel eastPanel;
JPanel centerPanel;

northPanel = new JPanel();
southPanel = new JPanel();
westPanel = new JPanel();
eastPanel = new JPanel();
centerPanel = new JPanel();

framePanel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
framePanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
framePanel.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
framePanel.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
framePanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Each panel may contain another `JPanel` or one of your components. One of the most useful and basic `LayoutManager` you can use to lay multiple components is `GridLayout`, that lets you specify a grid size (number of rows and columns): every time you add a component, it is placed in the first free slot starting from the upper left hand corner.

If you were to add 3 components to your `northPanel` you would code

```
northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

northPanel.add(component1);
northPanel.add(component2);
northPanel.add(component3);
```

These are just examples, you can find more info in the Java API's if you search for `LayoutManager`. Just some quick tips:

- You can specify a `Layout` directly in the `JPanel` constructor:

  `JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, columns));`
- You can add white spaces by inserting an empty `JPanel` in your grid places:

  ```
  JPanel whiteSpacePanel = new JPanel();   

  testPanel.add(component1);
  testPanel.add(whiteSpacePanel);
  testPanel.add(component2);
  ```
- You can specify some basic borders between `Components` in the `Layout` constructor

  `JPanel panelWithBorders = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, columns, xBorder, yBorder));`

References:

- [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html)
- [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)
- [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)
- [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for enlightening me !